# How to use Message Subscribe module?

Tags: notifications, message-subscribe

I have installed [Message Subscribe](https://drupal.org/project/message_subscribe) module. But I am not sure how to configure this. I also have installed all the required modules. I can see the Message Subscribe UI but there is nothing I can configure.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: what do you need it for ??

Comment: @Fahad:I need this so as users subscribe to content and be notified when content updates.

Comment: @Fahad:Any help on this please?

Comment: Actually I have not used this module yet. I asked you the question because I thought you might need to send emails or messages to subscribed users. For that I was thinking to sugest you simplenews or messages.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this question is old. This answer is for if is useful for others).
Message Subscribe module is a part of the [Message Stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145) system:

> The message stack comprises three main modules: Message, Message Notify and Message Subscribe.

You 'must' understand the concepts behind each of these modules and its integration to understand the Message Subscriber's role under this stack. As I understand, the module does not work as an isolated module. Also, please note that Message Subscribe uses the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to give users functionalities related to subscribe or not of its account to receive messages notifications related with the event that generates the message.

[Here](http://2014.pnwdrupalsummit.org/sites/default/files/slides/message-stack-slides.pdf) an interesting document about the Message stack to understand the main concepts behind the stack. Another resource [here](http://www.jacksonriver.com/news/message-stack).

Answer (score 1):

The [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe) module is part of the [Message Stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145), which consists of these modules (quotes are from the module's project page):

- [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message):

  > The Message module is the core of the message stack. It enables logging and displaying system events in a number of different use cases. Events that are recorded over time are sometimes call activity streams. Exportable messages subtypes can be created for different use cases with custom fields and display (view) modes.
- [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify).

  > This module provides a method for sending a message via a notifier plugin. Message Notify comes with plugins for email and SMS and may be extended to other transport mechanisms as required.
- [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe).

  > With this module, users who subscribe to content will be notified when events occur that involve that content. The module leverages the Flag module, which provides a subscribe functionality to users.

These are the basic components and dependencies of the message stack:

[image]

Just looking at the available documentation it's not obvious to get going with it. But if you want to have a closer look at the Message Stack in your own environment, then experiment a bit with the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer), together with the *Answers Notification* sub-module, which allows logged in users to ***subscribe*** to selected questions, so that they receive notifications (using the [Message Stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145)) when Questions receive Answers.