# Message subscribe module don't send emails

Tags: nodes, 9

I'm working on a project where I have to notify users when a new node is published or a new comment is created. To achieve this, I've installed the [Message subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe) module.

I've configured few flags that seem to work: Users can subscribe to new nodes; when I create a new node, I can flag it.

I've also configured messages, but when I create a new node, no email is sent to users.

I've taken a look at [Message Subscribe Module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180229) (tje module documentation) and I've found few hooks to make it work. I tried them, but they didn't help: No email is sent.

```php
function mymodule_notification_node_presave(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  // Get node where comment was posted.
//   $node = $comment->get('entity_id')->first()->get('entity')->getTarget()->getValue();
  // Call message notify service.
  if($node->isPublished()){   //uncomment if need to send only when node published.
  $notifier = \Drupal::service('message_notify.sender');
  // Create a message with node author as message creator.
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'node_notification', 'uid' => $node->getOwnerId()]);
  $message->set('field_text_message', 'text message');

  $message->save();
  // Send message to message creator(in this case = node author).
  $notifier->send($message);
  } //isPublished if close
}
```

```php
/*
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_notification_node_insert($node) {
  $message = message_create('node_notification', array('uid' => $node->uid));

  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', $message);
  $wrapper->field_node_ref->set($node);
  //$wrapper->save();  <-  don't need - message_notify_send_message does this

  $notifier = \Drupal::service('message_notify.sender');
  $notifier->send($message);
}
```

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function mymodule_notification_node_update(Node $node) {
  $message = Message::create([
    'template' => 'update_node',
    'uid' => $node->getOwnerId(),
  ]);
  $message->set('field_node_reference', $node);
  $message->set('field_published', $node->isPublished());
  $message->save();
  $subscribers = \Drupal::service('message_subscribe.subscribers');
  $subscribers->sendMessage($node, $message);
}
```

Do you have any idea about what I can do wrong?

I have also seen [How to use Message Subscribe module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88234/how-to-use-message-subscribe-module) but it didn't help me.

Comment: You have the [message notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify) module enabled?

Comment: You need to erase the `_notification` part. Your hook needs to be structure as `mymodule_node_presave(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {`

Comment: But my module is name like this, I've named it as "Mymodule_notification", Do you think it is better I rename it to avoid this problem ? (I've used drush to create the module template and name)

Comment: And yes I've enabled message notify

Comment: Add `\Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('It is working!');` and then check the Drupal log `/admin/reports/dblog` to see if you see the "It is working!" message, this way you can see/tell if your hooks are indeed firing.

Comment: Also, when you create a new account (logged out) over at `/user/register` are you getting the welcome/registration email? (Also check the spam folder) If you're not getting it, then your issue is not your custom module code.